# Using vector inputs to odeint in python scipy to solve a system of two differential equations

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am trying to solve a system of two coupled differential equations using python odeint().

In this system, a function f depends on two variables f(y,t) and another function g depends on one variable g(t). For example, something like that (illustrative only):

- df(y,t)/dt = (1 - y) + f(y,t) + g(t)
- dg(t)/dt = g(t)

I have tried using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

dy = 0.05
y = np.arange(0, 1 + dy, dy)
dt = 1
tmax = 100

t = np.arange(0,tmax,dt)
f = np.ones([tmax,len(y)])
g = np.ones(tmax)

def deriv(y,t):
    fi = y[0]
    gi = y[1]

    fprime = (1 - y) + fi + gi
    gprime = gi

    return [fprime, gprime]

# Initial conditions
f_ini = np.ones(len(y))*15          
g_ini = np.array([0.3])
sol_ini = np.concatenate((f_ini, g_ini), axis=0)

# solve the DEs
soln = integrate.odeint(deriv, sol_ini, t)
```

I get the following error at the last line of my code:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I am guessing that I am not setting my initial conditions correctly. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You might not have chosen the best set of equations: Your equations are independent of each other and the first one is a partial differential equation. With Sympy you're able to find closed form solutions:

```
from IPython.display import display
import sympy as sy
from sympy.solvers.ode import dsolve
from sympy.solvers.pde import pdsolve


sy.init_printing()  # LaTeX like pretty printing for IPython


t, y = sy.symbols("t, y", real=True)
f, g = sy.symbols("f, g", function=True)

eq1 = sy.Eq(g(t).diff(t), g(t))
g_sol = dsolve(eq1)
print("For the ode")
display(eq1)
print("the solution is")
display(g_sol)

eq2 = sy.Eq(f(y, t).diff(t), (1-y) + f(y, t) + g_sol.rhs)
f_sol = pdsolve(eq2)
print("For the pde")
display(eq2)
print("the solution is")
display(f_sol)
```

gives in an IPython interpreter

[image: solution]

You see that *g(t)* has an undetermined constant *C_1* and *f(t)* and undetermined function *F(y)*, which need to be defined by initial conditions.
If you know what your system behaves like at, e.g. time *t=0*, *C_1* and *F(y)* can easily be determined.

Comment: Many thanks, Dietrich. However, my equations are indeed coupled. In my example above, df/dt depends on g(t). And the actual equations I have to solve are coupled both ways. 

And although f(y,t) is a function of 2 variables, only the derivative with respect to t is involved. My program worked fine with odeint when I only had one equation to solve of the form:  df(y,t)/dt = (1 - y) + f(y,t)

Comment: It is difficult make generic statements on how to solve ODE systems. The solution strategy and its quality strongly depend on  the structure of the system. E.g., check out http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/ode.html#system-of-odes for a (incomplete) list of types of ODE systems.